# how to set InputStream data to FSDataInputStream in hadoop

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

There is a file compressed with bzip2 codec.

I decompress the the file and set the value to `InputStream`

```
InputStream inputStream = codec.createInputStream(fs.open(file));
```

Now I have to convert the `InputStream`  to `FSDataInputStream`.

Could some one please help me.

Comment: `new FSDataInputStream(inputStream);`? :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm only going to provide some code which implements the solution given by selalerer.

As selalerer explained, it's not possible to do this since you can't seek through the data and FSDataInputStream requires this. 
So you have to create an outputstream and write in it all the data of the inputstream, then it's posible to open said outputstream with FSDataInputStream.

Here's the code.

(Im assuming you're doing this in a RecordReader implementation where you have an object  FileSplit split which is compressed)

```
String uri=split.getPath().toUri().getPath();
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try{
          String outputUri =
                  CompressionCodecFactory.removeSuffix(uri, codec.getDefaultExtension());
          in=codec.createInputStream(fsin);
          out = fs.create(new Path(outputUri));
          IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, conf);

          fsin= fs.open(new Path(outputUri));
          end = Long.MAX_VALUE;
      }finally{
          IOUtils.closeStream(in);
          IOUtils.closeStream(out);
      }
```

Hope this is helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is at all possible. The bzip2 decoder may be doing the decoding as you read the file and doesn't save the parts already decoded and read. This means there's no way to seek through the data back and forth.

If this is case with the decoder, one option is to read all the data and then wrap it with an FSInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

The bare minimum you need is:

```
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration);
String path = "file://" + myFilePath;   // can include file extension
URI uri = new URI(path);
FSDataInputStream instrm = hdfs.open(new Path(uri));
```